# How to update only one property in google firebase data base

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have javascript code to connect with google Firebase data base. The data base has a ref messages and children. Some times, I only need to update one property in the last child node, for example I want to update

```
engineStatus
```

but not touch other fields. I use below code

```
this.firecircleFollowed.child(UserId).child(tempkey).set({
    engineStatus: 'EST:1'
})
```

But it will overwrite all filed and only leave engineStatus.

Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `set` which replace / overwrites the data use `update` :

```js
this.firecircleFollowed.child(UserId).child(tempkey).update({
    engineStatus: 'EST:1'
})
```

doc reference for [data updating](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Dadboz's correct answer, you can also call `set()` at the lower level property in the JSON:

```
this.firecircleFollowed.child(UserId).child(tempkey).child('engineStatus').set('EST:1')
```